# let current user delete a firebase child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to let the current user delete one of his posts (one of him created firebase childs), but with following code the just deletes all of him created childs... but I just want him to delete the selected child.

```
    Database.database().reference().child("jobs").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let forumPosts = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: AnyObject]] {
            for (key, _) in forumPosts  {
                Database.database().reference(withPath: "jobs").child(key).removeValue()
            }
        }
    })
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I guess I need to get the current postID of the child, but I don't know how I get it...

How I tried getting the postID:

```
let key = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId().key
```

UPDATE:

My Firebase Structure:

```
{
  "jobs" : {
    "-LZBUqFT5LqaQTaeYnv7" : {
      "addedByUser" : "user1",
      "imageDownloadURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...",
      "location" : "Olympia Ring, Berlin",
      "numberOfDislikes" : 12,
      "numberOfLikes" : 14,
      "text" : "Who needs a clean garden"
    },
```

The user deletes the post through a normal UIButton when it's getting pressed which is inside a normal ViewController
It's build up like this:

On the personal profile page is a TableView which shows only from the user created posts.
If the user now clicks on one of these cells he'll get to a DetailedVC of the selectedPost - and on this page is the button

EDIT2:

-LoZQBuYHH9CnwaZ1u4z

postID: "-LoZQ7jCAuJ6zxr9x1Fj"

Is there a way to get the original PostID?

EDIT3:

@IBAction func deleteJobPressed(_ sender: Any) {

```
    // Remove the post from the DB
    func deletePost(post: Job) {
        ref.child("jobs").child(post.postID!).removeValue()
    }
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

func download() {
    let refJob = Database.database().reference()
    refJob.child("jobs").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: "yourUserID").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let key = snapshot.key
        let data = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]
        let post = Job(postID: key, data: data)
        self.posts.append(post)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `for` there that is deleting the child for each of the values. Maybe it’s a good idea to add `postId` to your model and handle every reference to the database with that `postId`

Comment: I tried to get the postID to my model but all I get is an ID which is lightly changed by the original...

Comment: The code in your question will delete everything within `key` which is what the code issue is. However, there may be a higher level logic issue. How does the user select a post to delete? It is in a table or collection view? If so, how are you reading in the posts - can you include that code in your question along with a snippet of your firebase structure? To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. Update the question and we'll take a look

Comment: Ok, I've added the things you asked for in my question - would be nice if you could take a look at it :)

Comment: The value of  the child `addedByUser` should probably be the users uid who made the post. It's showing as "user1" so you may be using the uid but just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are actually making your model but here is how I would do it.

```
struct Post {
    var postID : String // This will be the postID from Firebase
    //.... Any other post info

    init (postID: String, data: [String : Any]) {
        self.postID = postID
    }
}

class PostDownloder {
    var posts : [Post] = []
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    func download() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("jobs").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: "yourUserID").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let key = snapshot.key
            let data = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]
            let post = Post(postID: key, data: data)
            self.posts.append(post)
        }
    }
}

class PostController : UIViewController { // Or whatever you are using

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //.... anything else you have
    }

    //... All your other methods

    func deletePost(post: Post) {
        ref.child("jobs").child(post.postID).removeValue()
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer. However, it won't work (as is). When using .observeSingleEvent it literally means 'do this once and only once' and because you're using .childAdded, it will only ever read the first first node and no others. So fix that part. Then, the OP has a child `addedByUser` which is what you want your .queryOrderedBy but then add a `.queryEqual(toValue: "user1")` so it will load that users posts, but as we know, that should probably be the users uid.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working because the postID is slightly different than the original ID, I'll update my question so its more understandable what I mean

Comment: @GifHunter111 There is no way Firebase are throwing the wrong IDs for a post. Make sure that you are downloading the data and creating your models correctly. Have a look at my answer, the initial part, I tested it and for me it works just fine.

Comment: I've done it according to your answer - it also doesn't give me any error... could you check my code please?

Comment: @GifHunter111, the code seems fine. I just tested it again and it is working as expected. Not sure where your error could be. If you want, share your project as a git and I can have a look. There is not much I can do with the info you gave.

Comment: This would be awesome, thanks a lot - but sadly my internet is too slow to upload it today, instead I could give you following dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/naf523drl425z7t/AADSUtqwJLE5WPOn5O-tgG39a?dl=0

Comment: Your code is wrong. You have a lot of methods that are not even called, also, you are trying to get the key of the post by calling .`childByAutoID`. What childByAutoID does is generate a new key to be stored in Firebase, it does not give you the key of the current post. That is why you are not able to delete them in the database. I'll fix your code a bit later and will upload it as a git.